# htacess URL Rewrite folder and links to main webpage

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect all my traffic from http://www.test.com/v/[anything after] to my main hope page test.com via a 301 redirect

Same for every url that is like: http://www.test.com/photos-3?[anything after] to again my home page.

Just to not mess something on my `.htacess` file i think is best to ask you guys.

Many thanks for help

Comment: for the first one i've added to my htaccess this: RedirectMatch 301 /v/(.*) /     it works but for ULS like v/Cars/Mercedes+Benz/Mercedes+Benz+SLS?g2_GALLERYSID=d2031cab0ee43104b3fb7a762fd367e1     it will redirect to www.test.com/?g2_GALLERYSID=d2031cab0ee43104b3fb7a762fd367e1

Comment: it should not keep the ?g2_GALLERYSID=d2031cab0ee43104b3fb7a762fd367e1

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(v/|photos-3) /? [L,NC,R=301]
```

`?` after `/` will strip off any query string in original URL.

Comment: does't work :( i've copied your code in my htacess, tried an URL like test.com/v/Cars/Mercedes+Benz/Mercedes+Benz+SLS?g2_GALLERYSID=d2031cab0ee43104b3fb7a762fd367e1  but 404 - no redirect :(

Comment: Did you place it in `/v/.htaccess` or at above level. Also try a new browser to avoid old cache in browser.

Comment: ok can you edit your question and place full & latest .htaccess in question

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ina/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ina/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(v/|photos-3) /? [L,NC,R=301]
</IfModule>

Comment: basically is just standard htaccess from WordPress and I've added at the end your line. nothing else.

Comment: This rule should be placed just below `RewriteEngine On` line in your .htaccess